# Silverlight Polling Duplex with HTTPS

Tags: silverlight, https, polling, duplex

Is it possible to have Silverlight Polling Duplex WCF working with HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Polling Duplex over HTTPS. If you are running the Silverlight app inbrowser make sure you set the client access policy so that it works with HTTPS

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/colinco/archive/2009/07/27/silverlight-3-ssl-and-clientaccesspolicy-xml.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTPS with polling duplex.

When setting the PollingDuplexHttpBinding you need to specify the correct BasicHttpSecurityMode (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsecuritymode%28VS.95%29.aspx).